# How to use cmder with powershell in VSCode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I use `cmder` as terminal inside `VSCode`. I was trying to integrate `powershell` with `cmder` inside `VSCode`.
I saw that in the `cmder` configuration for `powershell`, the following is being passed as parameters:

```
"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit -Command" "Invoke-Expression '. ''C:\\cmder\\vendor\\profile.ps1'''"
```

I tried to use this in `user.settings` like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit -Command \"Invoke-Expression '. ''C:\\cmder\\vendor\\profile.ps1'''\""]
```

However, the terminal crashes while opening.

I think I can use some help or guidance here. Thanks.

Comment: I would be surprised if you can get this working. Cmder is a console host not a shell. PowerShell.exe and cmd.exe are shells that are by default loaded by the Windows Console host, but can be loaded by others cmder, ConEmu, VSCode, et al. VSCode when it loads PowerShell is acting a console host itself trying to load a shell.

Comment: Hi! I see your point. However, setting up Cmder inside VSCode is relatively easy. Please check the last section here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal
I was trying to do the same with powershell with cmder. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass the arguments into that setting as one big string. It parses it by passing them in as comma separated.

I also found from [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7266#issuecomment-323991503) the `Invoke-Expression` method will never call the file so provided the correct way below.

Also, note the errors you see in the screenshot below are because the profile that comes with `cmder` is not coded correctly.

[image]

You would need to have your arguments added to the settings file in the following format:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-ExecutionPolicy",
    "Bypass",
    "-NoLogo",
    "-NoProfile",
    "-NoExit",
    "-Command",
    ". 'C:\\tools\\cmder\\vendor\\profile.ps1'"]
```

### Edit

Trying to figure out the error that is showing up there seems to be a bit of a bug because after opening `cmder` the environment variable `$env:CMDER_ROOT` shows properly. However, after starting it in Code as above it shows the CMDER_ROOT is set to `C:\` for some reason. Something you will have to figure out yourself or check with the folks that maintain the software.

Answer (score 1):

To fix path error You can set set path

```
$env:CMDER_ROOT = "path to CMDER e.g. D:\cmder_mini";
```